# Compressed Sparse Row Matrix vs. Adjacency List

Tags: boost, graph, complexity-theory, sparse-matrix, adjacency-list

The [Boost docs for compressed sparse row graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/graph/doc/compressed_sparse_row.html) mention:

> ...CSR graphs have much less overhead than many other graph formats (e.g., adjacency_list)...

What exactly is the improvement on overhead with CSR compared to an adjacency list? Both require O(|V| + |E|) memory to store the graph. I think time complexity for edge existence operations is the same as well.

What is this overhead referring to?

**Edit:** after some thought, I have a feeling that it could be because each element in each row of the matrix are stored in contiguous memory locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in the constant and in locality.

Keep in mind that O(n) may be n, 2*n or, fixed C, any C*n :)

Being stored in a contiguous region of memory it's less likely, during the execution of an algorithm, that the data needs to be fetched. This can improve the speed of the algorithm by another constant.